# How to treat whitespace in bash via Python?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to run the ffmpeg command to record the screen using the `subprocess` module. Everything is fine with this line:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-video_size", GivenSizeOfScreen, "-framerate", GivenRateOfFrames, "-f", "x11grab", "-i", ":0.0", "-q", GivenQuality, GivenPathAndName])
```

`GivenPathAndName` is something like `file:///home/user/Videos/test.mp4`. As I said, it's working. (It is in this form because I am getting the folder URI from a GTK widget).

However, the problem is when I select a folder with a white spaces. Like `file:///home/user/Documents/New Folder`. This will give me the following error in terminal:

```
file:///home/user/Documents/New%20Folder/test.mp4: No such file or directory
```

I know that this is because of bash misinterpreting the whitespace. And that I can actually run it with putting `\` before the whitespace to solve it. However, I couldn't manage to find a way to do that from Python sending it to Bash.

Comment: not sure it's bash since you didn't set `shell=True`. Can you try without the `file://` prefix? I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It looks like ffmpeg is accepting URLs, but that support is buggy.  Bash isn't involved here at all; the process is directly started by Python without an intermediate shell.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I didn't want to use shell=True because it's a security danger. Removing / putting file:// didn't change anything.

Comment: Try calling [`urllib.parse.unquote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) before passing the file name to ffmpeg.  (Or the corresponding function if you are on Python 2.)

Comment: @MHS Can you just rename that folder as `NewFolder`? :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank you! That did the trick. I hope you can put it as an answer so that I can accept it if someone reachs this page later.

Comment: @MHS Someone else already did.  I consider this a bug in ffmpeg, by the way, so if you can, please [file a bug report](https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing about the bash or python in cooperation with the bash. Here is a little example that shows that:

```
import sys
import os

for arg in sys.argv:  
    print arg
```

Starting this little script with the bash it'll give you the following:

```
$ ./arg_test.py this\ is\ a\ test
./arg_test.py
this is a test

$ ./arg_test.py "this is a test"
./arg_test.py
this is a test
```

And to be sure about the `file://`.

```
$ ./arg_test.py "file:///test test/"
./arg_test.py
file:///test test/
```

So the problem must be with how you get `GivenPathAndName` from your script or other parts of the program. In order to decode this url encoding use `urllib.parse.unquote()` for Python3 or `urllib.unquote()` for Python2.

```
import urllib
subprocess.Popen([
    "ffmpeg", 
    "-video_size", GivenSizeOfScreen, 
    "-framerate", GivenRateOfFrames, 
    "-f", "x11grab", 
    "-i", ":0.0", 
    "-q", GivenQuality, 
    urllib.parse.unquote(GivenPathAndName)
])
```